# How to use Google spreadsheet without using/adding/installing "include/vendor/autoload.php" can we use any online api or CDN?

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Currently My code is

```
require  'include/vendor/autoload.php';
//Reading data from spreadsheet.
$client = new \Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Google Sheets and PHP');
$client->setDeveloperKey("keysamplecode-Bx8ESgUfhUyQ2TR3yGix0jtFzcE");
$client->setScopes([\Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS]);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setAuthConfig('include/credentials.json');
```

How to update google spreadsheet without using the vendor folder in ftp. I mean is there any alternative option available to use any api instead of using autoload.php from vendor folder?
*Without the first line [  require  'include/vendor/autoload.php'; ]

Comment: You can download the library and put it wherever you want in your app and include the files you need manually. But then you'll get even more includes. Why is it a problem having one single `include`?  You can't load PHP code from CDN. Nor would you want to. If anyone took over that CDN, they would be able to execute code on your server, which would be _bad_!

Comment: I think you are missing the point. You should be able to run composer on your server and just simply `composer install` will populate the vendor folder there exactly like your local vendor folder. This does suppose you have included your composer.lock in you source management?

Comment: It's kind of take 70MB of memory space in FTP. Is there is any way to avoid/ not to use vendor folder in FTP to call autoload file from google spreadsheet. instead of this can we use any api or external link to call that in my site. Please let me know if it is possible. Thanks for your time and reply. Thanks once again.